# Software engineering stack question

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am about to start a new research project, and want to ask/poll the community on what technology stacks they think I should use beyond ones that I would provide and explain.  Where can I ask my software engineering question, preferable on Stack exchange, as I like the portfolio and community?

Answer (score 3):

> I am about to start a new research project, and want to ask/poll the community on what technology stacks they think I should use.

These are shopping questions and do not fit the Q&A standard so they are not to be asked on any sites on the network.

Comment: At most the OP could try one of the chatrooms, if there is one that's particularly on-topic and the audience is willing to discuss such topics.

Comment: Indeed. [*The Whiteboard* chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) over on Programmers might be a good choice for this – Software Engineering is generally [on-topic](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there, although polling for recommendations isn't (but the rules are more relaxed in the chat).